# why i can't use pow() function in pypy

Tags: python-3.7, pypy, pow

```
a = pow(4,-1,3)
print(a)
```

That code is worked in Python3.7.
But it's not working in pypy3.
this is error message :

> TypeError: pow() 2nd argument cannot be negative when 3rd argument specified

I want to pow() function using -1 in 2rd argument and integer in 3rd argument
help me!

Comment: The error explains the issue. For `pow(x,y[,z])`: If z is present, x and y must be of integer types, and y must be non-negative. [Source](https://www.journaldev.com/23002/python-pow)

Comment: um..it's working "pow(3,-1,223)"(myabe include extended extended Euclidean algorithm).

Comment: but it isn't working in pypy.so i add Euclidean algorithm source.it's working in pypy.
however it's very slow than python pow()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did it work with Python 3.7 when it is a 3.8 feature?

Quote from https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html :

> For integers, the three-argument form of the pow() function now permits the exponent to be negative in the case where the base is relatively prime to the modulus. It then computes a modular inverse to the base when the exponent is -1, and a suitable power of that inverse for other negative exponents.

With nightly build of PyPy 3.8:

```
Python 3.8.10 (cfd47581da0a, Jul 29 2021, 10:16:09)
[PyPy 7.3.6-alpha0 with GCC 7.3.1 20180303 (Red Hat 7.3.1-5)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
And now for something completely different: ``running pypy-c translate.py is a
bit like watching a thriller movie, it could die at any time because of the
32-bit 4GB limit of RAM''
>>>> a = pow(4,-1,3)
>>>> print(a)
1
```

With CPython 3.7 you get the expected ValueError:

```
Python 3.7.11 (default, Jun 29 2021, 16:09:17) 
[GCC 10.3.1 20210422 (Red Hat 10.3.1-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = pow(4,-1,3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: pow() 2nd argument cannot be negative when 3rd argument specified
```

Comment: Thank you sir!
I did it thanks to your comment!!